# Does $V\otimes_k K\cong W\otimes_k K$ imply $V\cong W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $V$ and $W$ be two $k$-vector spaces of the same dimension and $K/k$ any field extension. If $V\otimes_k K\cong W\otimes_k K$ as $K$-vector spaces then are $V$ and $W$ already isomorphic over $k$?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As soon as you said "of the same dimension" the spaces were isomorphic.

Comment: Ah yes. My eyes completely skipped over "of the same dimension", as it is both redundant and makes the problem trivial.

Comment: The question would be more interesting if you only require $k$ to be a commutative ring.

Comment: @ZhenLin But then the answer would just end up being no (once we removed the part about same dimension which would no longer make sense in general).

Comment: The answer is no in general. But then there's that business with faithfully flat descent...

Comment: @ZhenLin Certainly, once we let $k$ be an arbitrary commutative ring, some very nice and deep questions show up related to this.

Answer (score 5):

Yes: your conjecture can be proven simply by looking at the dimensions of the vector spaces. In particular, $\otimes_k K$ commutes with direct sums, and

$$ \left(\bigoplus_i k \right) \otimes_k K \cong \bigoplus_i K $$

so $\dim_k V = \dim_K (V \otimes_k K)$.

(note that it is important that you asked for them to be isomorphic as $K$-vector spaces, as $K \cong K \oplus K$ as $k$-vector spaces for any infinite dimensional extension, which means $V = k$ and $W = k^2$ would be a counterexample)